# Can a single desktop application use multiple SQL CE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an application that needs to store more than the SQL CE 4GB file size limit. Is it possible and allowed by Microsoft licensing for a single desktop application to use multiple SQL CE databases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, it's possible.  You just need to specify different connection strings to connect to different sdf files.

Legally, I don't have any information on SQL CE database.  I believe it should be okay but I am not 100% sure.  Actually, you can consider to use SQL Server Express Edition.  It's also free.  It has 10GB limit if you are using SQL Server 2008 R2 Express Edition no each database.  If you use older version, you still have 4GB limit. like SQL CE.  I am sure it's legal to have multiple databases running on the same SQL Server Express Edition at the same time.

There are some more benefit if you choose to use SQL Server Express Edition.  The only downside is that the installation of SQL Server Express Edition is a bit more complicated and takes more time.

***UPDATE***

Regarding to the license issue, I think you better check with Microsoft.  According to this [post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlce/thread/30a399f3-3cde-48b8-a744-29387ca57fff) on Microsoft forum, you can call 1-800-426-9400, Monday through Friday, 6:00 A.M. to 6:00 P.M. (Pacific Time) to speak directly to a Microsoft licensing specialist, and you can get more detail information from there.